# Open command prompt here context menu not working and showing error message

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, context-menu

When I shift right click the option is there but it only showing error like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj2em.jpg

Edit: I suspect that I accidentally delete the registry associated with this command or something when I uninstalled software and clean the leftover

Edit: Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Try repairing system files with SFC and DISM.

Comment: I've tried both. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations. That means I do not have any missing or corrupted system files

Answer (score 1):

The following shows [how to install](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12097-how-to-bring-back-the-open-command-window-here-in-windows-10) the `Open command window here` menu option in **Windows 10** from scratch (you did not state the OS). Perhaps reapplying it might help. In Regedit, go to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd
```

and take ownership. Then change value name

```
HideBasedOnVelocityId
```

to

```
ShowBasedOnVelocityId
```

You can also copy the following, save as a .reg file, and then execute:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
@="none"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\find]
"LegacyDisable"=""
"SuppressionPolicy"=dword:00000080
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\find\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{a015411a-f97d-4ef3-8425-8a38d022aebc}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:006698a6
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\UpdateEncryptionSettings]
"AppliesTo"="System.StorageProviderId:<>\"network\" AND System.StorageProviderProtectionMode:<>1 AND System.StorageProviderProtectionMode:<>2"
"AttributeMask"=dword:00002000
"AttributeValue"=dword:00002000
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\shell\\UpdateEncryptionSettings"
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000000
"MUIVerb"="@efscore.dll,-101"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"
"Position"="Bottom"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\UpdateEncryptionSettings\Shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\UpdateEncryptionSettings\Shell\Decrypt]
"AttributeMask"=dword:00002000
"AttributeValue"=dword:00002000
"CommandStateHandler"="{5B6D1451-B1E1-4372-90F5-88E541B4DAB9}"
"Icon"="edputil.dll,-1002"
"MUIVerb"="@efscore.dll,-103"
"ShowAsDisabledIfHidden"=""
"UpdateType"=dword:00000000
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{2F574F12-4EAA-46CF-BCBF-4E8055002E0C}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\UpdateEncryptionSettings\Shell\Decrypt\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{5B6D1451-B1E1-4372-90F5-88E541B4DAB9}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This suggests malware.

You should run a scan of your computer using Windows Defender.

Also scan using the [Malwarebytes free scan](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Avoid connecting any devices to your computer until you have eradicated the problem, because if it is malware, your computer may infect the other devices or damage the data they comtain.

Comment: I scanned with Windows Defender and Malwarebytes. No sign of malware.